# I can't add Audience network in Facebook developer account

Tags: ios, facebook-audience-network

I am trying to add an'Audience Network' in my Facebook developer account. But it always shows error. here is the error message. https://ibb.co/PT5q67r

I need your help. Thanks

Comment: You have posted an invalid screenshot URL. Can you try to post the correct URL?

Comment: this is error: https://ibb.co/PT5q67r

I filled all the filled but it show this is not available now